# trying to use [src] with url and variable

Tags: html, angular

In my component.ts file I have a list of users. I want to display them in my html.

**component.html**

```
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let user of users" class="contact-details">
       <img [src]="'https://app.compnay.com/{{user.profileImage}}' === ''? '../../../../../../../assets/images/empty-user-profile.png': 'https://app.company.com/{{user.profileImage}}'">
     </li>
   </ul>
```

I got this error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Got interpolation
>   ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 29 in
>   ['https://app.company.com.sa/{{user.profileImage}}' === ''?
>   '../../../../../../../assets/images/empty-user-profile.png':
>   'https://app.company.com.sa/{{user.profileImage}}'] in
>   ng:///ChatModule/ContactSearchResultListComponent.html@6:19
>   ("ass="contact-image">

Comment: FYI, `'https://app.compnay.com/{{user.profileImage}}'` can never be `''`. Maybe you meant to just check `user.profileImage === ''`

Comment: what about the else condition how it's going to be present without the url ?

Comment: See Vitalii's answer, but the condition is wrong to begin with, nothing to do with the `else` part.

Comment: Yes, the condition is wrong as @FedericoklezCulloca said. It has to do with Angular template engine, not your code itself. You are not allowed to use both template binding and interpolation in 1 statement.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already use Angular template binding through `[src]`, there's no need to use interpolation `{{}}` and that's why you are not allowed to and the error appears.

The correct syntax will be:

```
    <img [src]="user.profileImage === '' ? '../../../../../../../assets/images/empty-user-profile.png': 
   'https://app.company.com/' + user.profileImage">
```

However I encourage you to move that logic to *component.ts* and simply bind variable, e.g.

**HTML**

```
<img [src]="userProfileImage" />
```

**TS**

```
userProfileImage: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
   ...

   this.userProfileImage = user.profileImage === '' ? '../../../../../../../assets/images/empty-user-profile.png': 
   'https://app.company.com/' + user.profileImage;

   ...
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is woking fine,  but i still get not found error if there are no image, it should be replaced with the empty image provided in the else condition

Comment: i got https://app.company.com./attachment/stcuserimages/89888.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you check what is the value of user.profileImage ?

Comment: there is always a value but is not always found, the value is profileImage: "/bea/attachment/stcuserimages/999999.jpg"

Comment: You cannot foresee whether it will be found or not just by comparing it to the empty string. The complex solution is needed here. I would suggest querying image with AJAX request in the component and catch 404 in the error response. If that happens that means you cannot load the image.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users" class="contact-details">
    <img [src]="user.profileImage === ''?'../../../../../../../assets/images/empty-user-profile.png':'https://app.company.com/'+user.profileImage">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users" class="contact-details">
    <img [src]="user.profileImage === '' ? '../../../../../../.../assets/images/empty-user-profile.png' : 'https://app.company.com/' + user.profileImage ">
</ul>
```